# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to parse data from my Web API and show it on my react page, the connection is successful and the data is parsed (I can see an array of elements in the console) but whenever I want to show it on the page I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

I am using axios for the connection so here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Player extends React.Component {
    state = {
      loading: true,
      error: "",
      data: []
  };  

  loadData = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    return axios
      .get('http://localhost:6444/api/example')
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.setState({
          data: result.data.items,
          loading: false,
          error: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("error: ", error);
        this.setState({
          error: `${error}`,
          loading: false
        });
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.loadData();
    }

    render() {
      const { loading, error, data } = this.state;
      if (loading) {
        return <p>Loading ...</p>;
      }
      if (error) {
        return (
          <p>
            There was an error loading the players.{" "}
            <button onClick={this.loadData}>Try again</button>
          </p>
        );
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Players</h1>
          <p>{data.map((player, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index} player={player}></div>
            )})}</p>
        </div>
      );
    }   
}

export default Player;
```

I hope anyone can help me figure out the problem, I tried many things by now but nothing fixed the problem.

Comment: `result.data.items` is not returned in your response. You might want to try `result.data.items || []` or add an error if it's empty.

Comment: Can you also add what you see in console log when you do `console.log(result)`?

Comment: Can you post the output of `console.log(result);`?

Comment: {data: Array(16), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:6444/api/example", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: Array(16)
{...}
length: 16
__proto__: Array(0)
headers: {content-length: "798", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object

Comment: Is `result.data.items` also a non-empty array?

Comment: `result.data.items` is empty, hence you cannot use the `map` functions. `map` is applicable only for arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no items property inside results.data.  This should be enough.

```
this.setState({
  data: result.data,
  loading: false,
  error: false
});
```

Change the render for your div to put content inside the div

```
<p>{data.map((player, index) => {
  return (
    <div key={index}>{player}</div>
)})}</p>
```

Comment: I tried to change it and now I don't get the error anymore but the data is not displayed

Comment: Because there's nothing inside the div for player.

Comment: @MukeshSoni hes retrieving the `items ` not all data!

Comment: Yes. My answer has fixes for both the problems. The first code removes access to `result.data.items`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment including the output of `result`, you should change your state update to:

```js
this.setState({
  data: result.data,
  loading: false,
  error: false
});
```

Your data items must be directly on data, not under a key of `data.items`.